# When to use spy vs $httpBackend in jasmine

Tags: angularjs, testing, jasmine, restangular

I'm writing `Jasmine` code to test some `Restangular` logic.  I want to test that my 'Foo' `object` has been Restangulraized, so that the `foo.getList()` method will call `GET /foo` and return the result

I could test this in two ways.  I could add a `.spy` on `foo.getList()` and have it return the expected results.  Alternatively I can use `$HttpBackend.whenGET("/foo")` and set my expected results there.

Is one of these considered preferable?

I would assume `HTTPBackend` would be the better option, since it test 'later' in the logic flow. If I used a `spy` I couldn't prove, for example, that my Restangularize hadn't screwed up and was trying to resolve a different URL.

However, I'm looking at the inherited tests and they all use `spy`, and since I assume the person who wrote this code is better than me (they can't be more newbie then me at Angular) it makes me wonder if there is an advantage to the use of `spy` over `$httpBackend`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you are testing `foo.getList()`, use `httpBackend`. Once you test functions that only use `foo.getList()`, then use a spy. That's the most simple solution that avoids test duplication.

Note that you are writing unit tests. Every unit should be independent on other units.

Comment: Could you explain why each is more appropriate in each situation?

Comment: @Sulthan, could you please elaborate this more for the community with an example. It will really help understand better. Thanks much

Answer (score 3):

Let me see if I can explain what Sulthan meant.

Use httpBackend to write unit tests that test the REST API calls in order to mock the server API. In this case, you want to test that API makes the right calls with the right arguments and receives the right response without actually making an http request, so the server is the black box.

Use spy to test code that uses the client side API code. For example, a controller would use the client side Restangular service that calls the API. In this case, the black box is Restangular and only care about the expected response.